# Load HTML Elements Only When Button Is Clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code and since it will contain many images, I wanted to prevent these images from loading when the page loads to decrease page loading time. My idea was to prevent this code from running unless the user asks to do so by clicking a button. Thus loading the images only when the user wants to see them.

```
<div style="margin-top:40px;">
  <h3><a href='{parse url="showuser={$member['member_id']}&amp;tab=jawards" seotitle="{$member['members_seo_name']}" template="showuser" base="public"}'>{$this->lang->words['awards_title_post']}</a></h3>
  <div class="row2" style="padding:7px;">
    <foreach loop="profileawards:$awards as $a">
          <img class="tooltip" src='{$this->settings['upload_url']}/jawards/{$a['icon']}'
          <if test="size:|:$a['width']">
              width='{$a['width']}' height='{$a['height']}'
          </if>
          <if test="toolTip:|:$a['toolTip']">
              title='{$a['toolTip']}'
          </if>
          />
         <if test="awardCount:|:$a['count'] > 1">
             <span class='JLogicaAwardsCount'>{$a['count']}</span>
         </if>
         {$a['hook']['settings']['padding']}
    </foreach>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make an Ajax call. Try it out then ask a question, just asking others to write code for you without showing an attempt is not in the spirit of stack overflow

Comment: @JuanMendes, Yes Ajax will do as well. But I think what I posted as answer will suffice his requirement in more simpler way

Comment: @Juan Mendes, if I knew how to do that, I wouldn't be asking this question. :)

Comment: @Anthony do a Google search on AJAX tutorials, try it out, and ask a more focused question if you can't get it to work

Answer (score 0):

You can try following js

```
  <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"><<<< this goes in the header 
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".button").click(function(){
        $(".hiddendiv").slideToggle();
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>



    <input type="button" class="button" >123</button>
        <div class="hiddendiv">
             your data to show
        </div>
     </div>
    </body>

    <style>
        .hiddendiv { 
    display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Jkumar. My intention was to prevent the code from loading completely. Hiding it works, but I wanted to make the page load faster by reducing the amount of images the browser needs to download. Hiding it will still download these images.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever data that you want to show only when user clicks the button, collect it in a javascript variable.

```
var myHeavHtml = ""; \\all data with images.
```

Say there is button on the page id btnLoadImages

```
var isImagesLoaded = false;
$('#btnLoadImage').on('click', function(e)
{
    if(!isImagesLoaded)
    {
       $('#imgContainer').html(myHeavyHtml);
       isImagesLoaded = true;
    }
    else
    {
       $('#imgContainer').toggle();
    }
});
```

On the page load, declare a variable isImagesLoaded set to false, means you have not loaded the images. So when it is false, add the html to container div.All other times, just toggle the hide & show.

In this way, the images will not be loaded when the page is loading, it will inserted only when you click the button.

Hope this suffice your requirements.